# How to click a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

hi I have no idea how to use js so this is my first time working with it anyways

`document.getElementById("no-touch enablePrint paidUser v2reader page-student page-student-reader page-student-reader-3053671 page-student-reader-3053671-notes pageReader").click;`

when I run this I get that error anyway to make it click?

Comment: What error do you get when running that code?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Comment: what kind of id is this?? Are you sure your query is correct. Also you need to call the click function, so it will be `.click()`

Comment: okay... so... what you have in the params... does not look like an id... but a long string of classes...

Comment: I think your `getElementById` query is incorrect. As others said, you probably need to use a different selector query.

Comment: Oh ok well thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = () =>{
  document.body.style.background = 'red';
}

// Auto Click

document.getElementById("demo").click();
```

```html
<button id='demo'>save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query is a list of class names. In that case, you can use `document.getElementsByClassNames` like this:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassNames("no-touch enablePrint paidUser v2reader page-student page-student-reader page-student-reader-3053671 page-student-reader-3053671-notes pageReader");

// elements will be an array
// If you know this will only find one element, you can do this:
if (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].click();
}

// If you know it may find multiple elements, something like this:
elements.forEach(el => el.click());
```

Or you can give your element a unique `id` such as

```html
<div id="some-id">Some Div</div>
```

and then you can use `document.getElementById("some-id").click()`

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById is expecting only one `id`. You can use `querySelector` instead of getElementById but you'll need to find a valid css selector to get to this element. For example:

```js
document.querySelector(".page-student-reader-3053671").click();
```

I assumed that `page-student...` is a class. Thats why I added a `.` in front of it in the parameters.